# Inject a YAML file into a constructor

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have this YAML file `src/main/resources/foo.yml`:

```yaml
bar:
  - hello
  - world
baz:
  - lorem
  - ipsum
```

And this component:

```java
@Component
public class MyComponent {
    public MyComponent(Map<String, List<String>> foo) {
        // foo.get("bar")
    }
}
```

Using Spring Boot 2.7, is it possible to inject the configuration as-is (own file, no prefix, no class) into a constructor?

Answer (score 1):

If you want spring to do the parsing for you... I suggest you put your config in `src/main/resources/application.yaml`

Eg

```yaml
foo:
   bar:
     - hello
     - world
   baz:
     - lorem
     - ipsum
```

You could then do

```java
public class Foo {
   private List<String> bar;
   private List<String> baz;

   // getters / setters
}

@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {
   @Bean 
   @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "foo") 
   public Foo foo() {
      return new Foo();
   }
}

@Component
public class MyComponent {
    private final Foo foo;

    public MyComponent(Foo foo) { 
       this.foo = foo;
    }
}
```

See [configuration-properties-in-spring-boot](https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be

```java
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;

@Component
public class MyComponent {
    private final Map<String, Object> foo;

    public MyComponent(@Value("classpath:foo.yaml") Resource yamlResource) { 
       Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
       this.foo = yaml.load(yamlResource.getInputStream());
    }
}
```

But I'd probably do the yaml parsing in a `@Configuration` and then inject that into `MyComponent` which might make it simpler to share / mock the values in the yaml file

```java
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {
   @Bean
   public Map<String, Object> foo(@Value("classpath:foo.yaml") Resource yamlResource) {
      Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
      return yaml.load(yamlResource.getInputStream());
   }
}

@Component
public class MyComponent {
    private final Map<String, Object> foo;

    public MyComponent(@Qualifier("foo") Map<String, Object> foo) { 
       this.foo = foo;
    }
}
```

Comment: So it's not possible to let Spring do the parsing?

Comment: See my other answer